# How to display tumblr blog info?

Tags: php, javascript, tumblr

Hi I want to customize my tumblr theme without using a third party apps so I could customize the styles for it. I want to display my number of post, followers and following. I know i will be using php for it? or something. Thank you. I tried to research about this thing but i end up nothing i don't what's the exact words.

Comment: If my answer below was useful or correct, please accept it so that I can be awarded the points. You accept by clicking on the check mark displayed beside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way is to edit your Tumblr theme under the "customize appearance" setting.

Here are options: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Examine other free templates to get an idea how to use.

Anything you want to do beyond that will probably require javascript and the API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

And anything past that will probably require a combination of Javascript with JSON access to your own server where relevant info is stored. Relevant info can be gathered a number of ways, such as a PHP script scraping your dashboard, or a Greasemonkey script scraping your dashboard, etc.

Another advanced option similar to that would be to have a script automatically edit and update your template. That could even be done many ways, such as purely with Greasemonkey or even probably a bookmarklet.

Of course, now that I think about it, depending on your goals, you could just manually update any information as you see fit, and skip any advanced coding.